# Authenticating to Azure Manage Grafana HTTP API (terraform provider) with Azure AD service principal

Tags: azure, terraform, grafana

As a part of one Terraform deployment I would like to deploy [Azure Managed Grafana](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/dashboard_grafana) and some Grafana resources (using [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/grafana/grafana/latest/docs) provider). Managed Grafana integrates with AD and it is possible to call Grafanas HTTP API with AAD token ([az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/grafana?view=azure-cli-latest) is doing that), just do not know how to generate it and the authenticate to Terraform provider.

EDIT:
So my temporary solution is to generate token before running terraform plan / apply end set it as a environment variable - not ideal for development.

```bash
export GRAFANA_AUTH=$(az account get-access-token --resource="ce34e7e5-485f-4d76-964f-b3d2b16d1e4f" --query accessToken --output tsv)
# or

export GRAFANA_AUTH="$(curl -X POST \
  -d "client_id=${ARM_CLIENT_ID}" \
  -d "client_secret=${ARM_CLIENT_SECRET}" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
  -d "resource=ce34e7e5-485f-4d76-964f-b3d2b16d1e4f" \
  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${ARM_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token" \
  | jq -r .access_token)"
```